# How to destructure an object to retrieve the return value from a method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, immutability, destructuring

I was working with immutability and redux and I am facing a problem which isn't grave but if there is a solution for it, then that would be great. Answer might be silly but since I am new to ES, I am thinking how can we achieve it.

Below is my reducer:

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import { TODOYO } from '../constants/action-types';

const initialState = Immutable.Map({
  message: null,
});

export default function todos(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TODOYO:
      return state.set('message', action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Below is my mapStateToProps function in a component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const message = state.todos.get('message');

  return {
    message,
  };
}
```

How can I destructure `state` to retrieve the message?

I was thinking something like this:

```
const {
  todos: {
    message: get('message')
  }
} = state;
```

which is wrong. Is there a way to retrieve message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `message` as one of the keys of your state, you can do this using the [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) syntax. If message does exist as a property on your state, the default will be overridden. So use with caution.

```
function mapStateToProps({ todos, message = todos.get('message') }) {
  return {
    message,
  };
}
```

And you can also shorten `mapStateToProps` to an arrow function:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ todos, message = todos.get('message') }) => ({
  message
});
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. You can only destructure arrays/objects, not execute functions within the destructuring.

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to extract data from **arrays** or **objects** into distinct variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: This could be nice to do something like `const {length, firstLetters: substring(0, 5)} = string;` imo.